# Bind string and bool in a ListView?

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

I have a ListView that contains a TextBlock and a Checkbox.

I have bound the TextBlock to a String:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
//Stuff
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" x:Name="Text">
```

Now I also want to have a Checkbox that can be toggled and bound to a List. I couldn't manage to bind a bool to it. My current way is: I toggle the box and I can get the Parent, find something called "Text", get it's Text, look up the Index of it in my ObservableCollection that is bound and it's also the index of my checkbox! That works, but Binding would work a lot nicer. Is there a way to do it with binding??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is so easy and you can write a converter to convert the string to bool.

```
public class StringToBoolConvert : IValueConverter
{
    public string TrueString { get; set; } = "true";

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (TrueString.Equals(value?.ToString()))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And then you can add the StringToBoolConvert to the resource.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:StringToBoolConvert x:Key="StringToBoolConvert" TrueString="1"></local:StringToBoolConvert>
</Page.Resources>
```

You can use the StringToBoolConvert in the DataTemplate.

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind List}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Text" Text="{x:Bind}" ></TextBlock>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource StringToBoolConvert}}"></CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

We write some code to bind in ListView.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> List { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "1", "2", "3"
    };
```

And we use the StringToBoolConvert and set the TrueString where the value is true and when we check the CheckBox.

For we set the TrueString to "1" and we will check the CheckBox when the value is "1". Try to run the code and you will view this image.

[image]